# Return 1 row from all groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=9e6f83edf836f4496afb509eb9411d4a

Edited to include sql code:

```
CREATE TABLE TMP_PRODUCTS (STORE INT, UPC INT, PROMOCODE CHAR(3), FORSALE CHAR(1))

INSERT INTO TMP_PRODUCTS VALUES
(100,1,'123','Y'),
(100,2,'123','Y'),
(100,3,'123','N'),
(100,4,'124','Y'),
(100,5,'124','N'),
(100,6,'124','N'),
(100,7,'125','N'),
(100,8,'125','N'),
(100,9,'125','N');

SELECT
    STORE,
    UPC,
    PROMOCODE,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY STORE ORDER BY PROMOCODE) AS 'GroupCode'
FROM
    TMP_PRODUCTS
WHERE
    FORSALE = 'Y'
```

I need to return all rows where FORSALE='Y' across all groups of PROMOCODE, and also at least 1 row from all groups where FORSALE='N'.  In this example all products from group 125 are FORSALE='N', but I need at least 1 row to return.  Here is the output I am currently getting:

```
STORE   UPC     PROMOCODE   GroupCode   FORSALE
100     1       123         1           Y
100     2       123         1           Y
100     4       124         2           Y
```

But here is the ideal output I would like to get:

```
STORE   UPC     PROMOCODE   GroupCode   FORSALE
100     1       123         1           Y
100     2       123         1           Y
100     4       124         2           Y
100     7       125         3           N
```

It would also be completely acceptable to return 1 row from PROMOCODE 123 and 124 even though they already have some items that are FORSALE='Y'.  So this would also be acceptable outcome:

```
STORE   UPC     PROMOCODE   GroupCode   FORSALE
100     1       123         1           Y
100     2       123         1           Y
100     3       123         1           N
100     4       124         2           Y
100     5       124         2           N
100     7       125         3           N
```

Comment: A fiddle is great, but a question here should be self-contained, i.e. have both sample table data and the expected result specified - all as formatted text (not images.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with an additional row number window function to always include 1 row from each group regardless of Y/N

```
select STORE, UPC, PROMOCODE, Dense_Rank() over (partition by STORE order by PROMOCODE) GROUPCODE, FORSALE
from (
    select * , Row_Number() over(partition by STORE, PROMOCODE order by UPC) rn
    from TMP_PRODUCTS
)x
where FORSALE = 'Y' or rn=1
```

Comment: I don't think this guarantees that one row is `N`.

Comment: I think perhaps it's just down to the ordering, in hindsight if the rownumber ordering was by forsale then that would mean every promocode group would always have a "N" if it existed as the first row so would be included.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the logic you want is:

```
SELECT STORE, UPC, PROMOCODE,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY STORE ORDER BY PROMOCODE) AS GroupCode
FROM (SELECT P.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY STORE, PROMOCODE, FORSALE ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as seqnum
      FROM TMP_PRODUCTS P
     ) P
WHERE FORSALE = 'Y' OR seqnum = 1;
```